# How to run Vue unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

I'm following this tutorial to implement Vue unit test: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/unit-testing-vue-components.html

However, after creating a component and a test component, I have no idea how to actually run the test. My test file is located in test/unit/myfirsttest.spec.js. Do I need to run a command or configure something?

Thanks so much in advance,

Comment: Have added vue test utils to your project? If you did, just run `npm run test:unit`. If not, Add vue test utils by running this command, `vue add @vue/unit-jest`

Comment: Thanks, I have found a way to run it.